# How to check for existing Google Maps API key in my plugin

Tags: wordpress

In my plugin for Wordpress I unqueue the googlemaps js but I manually pasted my api key:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'google_js', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[my api key here]&callback=initMap', '', '' ); // google maps api
```

So how can I get this api key the right way in wp?

Maybe there is a standard way to store and get this api key?

Comment: Probably best way to go for you is to create and retrieve an option. 
Check [the wordpress codex for options](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option) and the underlying concept of it.

Comment: That's a good point, but then again is there a standard wp name for "google maps api key" option? Because whole point is to retrieve this key if it was already set outside my plugin.

Comment: Within the wordpress universe it is very uncommon to "share" settings between plugins or themes that are not related to the core wordrpess features. So as long you are not developing against a set of plugins or a certain theme which you know utilize a Google Maps API Key there is no reliable way implementing such a functionality. It would require a heuristic about how (other) developers would potentially name their Google Maps API Key options and this is not reliable per definition.